# How to add multiple images to a post in Web2py?

Tags: database, web2py

I am working to make a forum where people can post questions.In a question, i want to add a facility for the user to add multiple images corresponding to the question. So how can i achieve that in Web2py? What should i add in my question database and the corresponding view?

Comment: You can limit the number of images and add extra upload fields to your question table. That is the simplest solution. If you want any number of images possible you probably need to introduce some sort of a image_per_question table and quite a bit of more work. So how many images per question do you want to support?

Comment: Any number of images.

Comment: And you want all of these to be posted simultaneously along with the original post? Or first a post and than one attachment and then another?